# What is a more common substitute for Shaoxing cooking wine?

Tags: substitutions, asian-cuisine, chinese-cuisine, wine

I have never cooked with Shaoxing wine, so I'm not sure what would be its best substitute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pale Dry Sherry.

http://chinesefood.about.com/od/cookingfaqs/qt/rice_wine_sub.htm