# What's the better substitute for Shaoxing wine?

Tags: substitutions, chinese-cuisine

We've had a number of questions about Shaoxing wine, [including this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/63537/questions-about-shaoxing-wine).  However, I have one that I haven't seen directly addressed either here or on the outside websites I've been able to find:

Is straight dry sherry *actually* the best substitute for Shaoxing wine?  Or would a mix be better?

Details: I live in the US state of Oregon.  Due to liquor import restrictions here, I cannot buy real Shaoxing wine; just the awful "cooking" wine.  In addition to its low quality, I have to cook for someone on a low-salt diet so salted cooking wine is unacceptable.

The [conventional recommendation](https://www.gourmetsleuth.com/ingredients/detail/shaoxing-wine) for replacing Shaoxing wine is [pale dry sherry](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19667/what-is-a-more-common-substitute-for-shaoxing-cooking-wine).  However, this advice is usually based on the assumption that the asker has no access to Chinese ingredients of any kind.  So I'm asking if some mixture of sherry, sake, and/or Chinkiang vinegar might be a better flavor substitute. Since I plan to use this in a sauce where the wine would normally be the majority of the liquid, I'd like to do better if possible.

So, would a mix be a better substitute than straight sherry, and if so, what proportions?

Comment: Do you have access to mirin?

Comment: Yes.  Or I can make it from sake.

Comment: Why would you expect the best substitute to be "something Chinese"?

Comment: Sneftel: I don't understand why you're asking that question, since you're not quoting me.

Comment: The ingredients you suggested were Asian, but taste nothing like shaoxing wine. Why would a Chinese food store have a better substitute for shaoxing wine than a liquor store? Chinese cuisine doesn't need a substitute; it has shaoxing wine.

Comment: Sneftel: if you have a substitution suggestion, post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think mirin is going to be sweeter than shaoxing wine. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UyKUI5U67k) link however has much more information about shaoxing wine, and they say that a Japanese sake, sherry, or even a white wine could be substituted depending on context.

This is outside the scope of the question, but have you checked Uwajimaya?

Comment: Yes, I have checked there.  The problem is that Shaoxing isn't on the "Oregon List", which means that it's illegal to import into the state of Oregon.